# Formatting lists to display leading zero - Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, list, matrix, format

I'm trying to create a matrix with 4 rows and 10 columns and display the leading 0 for all the single digit numbers that will randomly get generated later. This is what I would like it to look like: [image: 1] My teacher gave me this snippet as a way to format the numbers:

```
print('{:02}'.format(variable))
```

But when I use this in my function, it gives me the error: **unsupported format string passed to list.__format__**

I reworked my code and was able to get the leading zero, but now the 4x10 matrix is just 40 ints side by side. Anyone able to give me some help and an explanation?

My code:

```
def printMatrix(matrix):
    for r in range(ROWS):
        for c in range(COLS):
            print('{:02}'.format(matrix[r][c]), end=' ')

def main():
    matrix = [0]*ROWS
    for i in range(ROWS):
        matrix[i] = [0]*COLS

    printMatrix(matrix)
```

Comment: ROWS and COLS are constants. ROWS = 4 & COLS = 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close, looks like you may just need another `print()` after the `for`-loop to put a newline after each row. Try this:

```
def printMatrix(matrix):
    for r in range(ROWS):
        for c in range(COLS):
            print('{:02}'.format(matrix[r][c]), end=' ')
        print()
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/@downshift/LemonchiffonColorfulWifi)

Answer (score 0):

you need a 0 in front .. i.e. {**0**:02}

```
print('{0:02}'.format(variable))
```

This 0 refer to the index of the parameters passed in e.g. this should work too:

print('{**2**:02}'.format("x", "y", **variable**))

---

Your code:

```
def printMatrix(matrix):
    for r in range(ROWS):
        for c in range(COLS):
            print('{0:02}'.format(matrix[r][c]), end=' ')

def main():
    matrix = [0]*ROWS
    for i in range(ROWS):
        matrix[i] = [0]*COLS

    printMatrix(matrix)
```